# Write csv file from text file without empty lines in Python

Tags: python, csv

I trying to create csv file from txt file with only one row.

Txt file looks like this:

[image]

My code is:

```
row = []
with open('vehicles.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as r:
    r = len(r.readlines())
with open('vehicles.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for i in range(r):
        data = {
            'vehicle': f.readline().strip()
        }
        row.append(data)
        csv_title = ['vehicle']
with open('vehicle.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=csv_title)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(row)
```

But csv file creates with empty rows

[image]

How can I remove these empty lines?
When I print this in the terminal, it goes without empty lines

edit:

Adding a newline="" also doesn't help. The csv files still goes with empty rows

Comment: add `newline=""`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thank you, for your answer, but I also have tried this and it didn't help me

Comment: You show the initial file in one manner, then the second one in a different manner. **A CSV file is a text file**. Please show both file read with the same tool. That being said besides striping lines your code only adds an initial line: no need of the csv module for that...

Comment: the way you're reading your csv file is ... not the proper way. It's terrible. Use `csv.DictReader` instead. Plus [edit] your question to show where you inserted `newline=""` because it's not clear

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I can't understand why I need to use "csv.DictReader" if I want to create and write a file, not to read. And can you please point me to why my way is terrible? I use "newline" in the part, where I create a csv file, so it is in the last "open with". Thanks for your reply

Comment: it's terrible because you don't need 2 passes to read a text file. Then are you _sure_ you tried with newline="" because I don't see why it would fail, unless your textfile contains empty hidden lines. Try printing `row` from python before dumping it to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, my issue was, that the txt file has some symbols, that made a empty rows, and cause the txt file is large it hard to notice this symbols.

So I **changed the** **encoding to** **utf-16** and it made me csv file as I want it to be maded